# Flutter web DevTools network tab missing

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-devtools

I tried to debug my app using flutter devtools, but when I run my app as web application on chrome or edge, some tabs like network are missing in the flutter devtools:
[image]

Is there any way to use network tab and other missing tabs in flutter web?

Comment: I have same issue, did you found any solution?

Comment: @WebMaster Not yet, but you can use inspect element to monitor network requests